# gstreamer access dynamicaly created elements to add pad probe

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I need to access dynamicaly created sub-element of **glvideomixer** element (its derivation of compositor)
It has its own bin and its sub-elements are created into this bin.

Is it possible to access such sub-elements if I have pointer to the glvideomixer element and to the pipeline?

Is there some kind of "sub-element-created" signal? - I need to access the subelement right after its created

All this I am doing to be able to add pad probes to these elements to analyse what is flowing through them.

This is how I created glvideomixer:

```
GstElement *video_mixer = gst_element_factory_make ("glvideomixer", NULL); 
//.. wait for creating inner structure and ASAP get element and
```

This is the part of pipeline showing just the glvideomixer's bin:
[image]

I need to access **mixer** element (and then the others with autogenerated names - gluploadelement# glcolorconvertelement# ..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a listener on the `glvideomixer` bin for the `element-added` signal:

```
void my_callback(GstBin *glvideomixer_bin, GstElement *element, 
       gpointer user_data) {
   //call gst_element_get_name and verify that it's "mixer"
}

g_signal_connect(GST_BIN(glvideomixer), "element-added", 
    G_CALLBACK(my_callback), my_data);
```

You can also just use `gst_bin_get_by_name` if the mixer element happens to get created immediately:

`GstElement* mixer = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(video_mixer), "mixer")`

then unreference it when you're finished:

`gst_object_unref(mixer);`

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/stable/gstreamer/html/GstBin.html#GstBin-element-added